# Handling error when using [].reduce to call several functions sequentially

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have the following code to run 15 promises sequentially:

```
[func1, func2, func3, ...etc].reduce((prev, curr) =>
  prev.then(curr).catch(console.error)
, Promise.resolve())
```

The problem is: When a error happens inside of one of the functions, the following error popups in my terminal:

```
Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined
```

I've searched, but wasn't able to find someone with the same error. Is there a workaround?

Thank you.

Comment: Is `reduce` being called inside of one of those functions. An error inside the `reduce` shouldn't cause that message on the original reduce.

Comment: That probably means one of `func1`..`funcN` have another reduce statement, which is failing... Check your error stack, and perhaps paste that here as well!

Comment: Please post an [mcve] with some simple demo functions for which the error happens.

Answer (score -1):

My crystal ball says that *inside* of one of these functions you are using `reduce` on the array that you receive as an argument, as the result of the previous function.

The problem with that is when an error happens, your `.catch(console.error)` does *handle* it immediately and returns a promise that is fulfilled with `undefined` (the return value of `console.error(…)`). This result is then passed to the next function, which is executed regardless of the error. You'll want to handle the error in the end only:

```
[func1, func2, func3, …].reduce((prev, curr) =>
  prev.then(curr)
, Promise.resolve()).catch(console.error)
```

Comment: Are you sure it will be work? Because I don't think so, prev still will be undefined.

Comment: `prev` never was `undefined`, it always is a promise (in my code as well as in the original one). (I guess that) the problem was that it was a promise that was fulfilled with `undefined`.

Comment: Hi Bergi! Actually I'm not, I'm parsing a JSON that is not really a JSON to test it.

Comment: @Celo Yes, that's the first error. It should get logged and the chain promise is getting resolved to `undefined`. The next function in the chain then tries to call `.reduce` on the presumed JSON array, which doesn't work of course, and causes the second error message that you're now asking about. But as I said in the question comments, for any more detailed diagnosis we need a complete sample of the non-working code.

Comment: I understand. Actually, I was able to figure it out the problem. I'm not using `;`, so the interpreter were concatenating the line before the reduce... --".

Comment: I think your crystall ball is right. And also just because of that rejection handling problem (can't break a  `.reduce())` i think sequencing by recursion is a way better idea.